# Font not selected in Angular 10

Tags: css, angular, sass, less

I have created my scss project in Angular and when I try to add a font, I get an error, how do I fix the problem?

style.scss:

```
@import "~@angular/material/theming";
@include mat-core();
$PWP-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$PWP-accent: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$PWP-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$PWP-theme: mat-light-theme($PWP-primary, $PWP-accent, $PWP-warn);
@include angular-material-theme($PWP-theme);


@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
@import './variables.scss';
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: $font-vazir-bold;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

variables.scss:

```
   $font-vazir-bold:"Vazir";
    @font-face {
        font-family: Vazir;
        src: url("../assets/font/vazir-font-v27.2.0/Vazir-Bold.eot");
        src: url("../assets/font/vazir-font-v27.2.0/Vazir-Black.ttf") format("ttf");
    }
```

Inside the file (angular.json) I changed the path of the style.scss file.

angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "PWP": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/PWP",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/scss/styles.scss",
              "src/scss/mixin.scss",
              "src/scss/variables.scss",
              
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "PWP:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "PWP:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "PWP:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/scss/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "PWP:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "PWP:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "PWP",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "c792c032-9136-42b5-8b0a-391b6f8d84c5"
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "pwp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.7",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Error in console:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/app/layout/home/home.component.scss
Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: E:\project\PwpEnd\PWP\src\scss\variables.scss:5:4: Can't resolve '../assets/font/vazir-font-v27.2.0/Vazir-Bold.eot' in 'E:\project\PwpEnd\PWP\src\app\layout\home'

  3 | @font-face {
  4 |     font-family: Vazir;
> 5 |     src: url("../assets/font/vazir-font-v27.2.0/Vazir-Bold.eot");
    |    ^
  6 |     src: url("../assets/font/vazir-font-v27.2.0/Vazir-Black.ttf") format("ttf");
  7 | }
```

**How do I fix this problem?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12vse.png)

Comment: Is `variables.scss` and `styles.scss` in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, they are in a folder

Comment: When I import into the home component, I get variables, or an error

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   @font-face {
        font-family: Vazir;
        src: url("~/assets/font/vazir-font-v27.2.0/Vazir-Bold.eot");
        src: url("~/assets/font/vazir-font-v27.2.0/Vazir-Black.ttf") format("ttf");
    }
```

Ans from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6599
I have same problem ,and it work for me

Answer (score 0):

The address of the photos must be given from the root, as follows

```
$font-vazir-bold:"Vazir";
    @font-face {
        font-family: Vazir;
        src: url("src/assets/font/vazir-font-v27.2.0/Vazir-Bold.eot");
        src: url("src/assets/font/vazir-font-v27.2.0/Vazir-Black.ttf") format("ttf");
    }
```